# Excel Increasing number of cells by group

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Lets say I have 1397 groups of 5 Cells like this:

Group 1

> 0000
>   0000
>   0000
>   0000
>   0000

etc.

I want to increment each group by 1 in excel, how can I achieve this? So the following is example:

> 0000
>   0000
>   0000
>   0000
>   0000
>
> 0001
>   0001
>   0001
>   0001
>   0001
>
> 0002
>   0002
>   0002
>   0002
>   0002

Is there a Formula or Macro that I can use to achieve this?

The cells are going down in rows.

Answer (score 2):

Set group1 (the first row) to zeros. Let's say the cells are `A1:E1`, we set them all to 0.

In the leftmost cell of row 2 (`A2`), type the formula `=A1+1`

Select the cell `A2` and copy (CTRL+C)

Select the range `A2:E1397` paste (CTRL+V)

Select the whole range, `A1:E1397`

`Format cells` -> `Custom`

In the `Type` textbox, type `0000` and press `OK`

Comment: all that did is change everything to 0000

Comment: @HC17758091 oops sorry, the formula to type in A2 is `=A1+1`.

Comment: Another approach would be `=row()-1` in each column

Comment: @DanH. sure. But I usually prefer the method above because it's a general technique that I use to generate sequences. I can control the increment, I can have different starting values, etc.

Answer (score 0):

a `VBA` way

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim i As Long

    ReDim arr(1 To 1397) As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        arr(i) = i - 1
    Next i
    With Range("A1:E1").Resize(UBound(arr))
        .value = Application.Transpose(arr)
        .NumberFormat = "0000"
    End With
End Sub
```